# Bootstrap - auto close behavior (dropdown menu) inside navbar shiny app

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, bootstrap-5

I'd like to change shiny navbarMenu behaviour - when I click inside or outside, dropdown hide and i need to click again to drop it again. Maybe someone have tried change behaviour on bootstrap manual close data-*bs-auto-close="false"* inside shiny app?

In html it looks like that:

`

```
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuClickable" data-bs-     toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="false" aria-expanded="false">
    Manual close
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuClickable">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Shiny can be restrictive when it comes to adding your own bootstrap classes to the generic UI functions. You can, however, construct the entire UI using html tags like I've done below.

Notice that I used `bootstrapPage` and `theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5)` to tell Shiny I want to use Bootstrap 5. I can add any custom bootstrap classes by using a named argument. For example, I used `"data-bs-auto-close" = "false"`.

Here is a reconstruction of the HTML you shared written in R code.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
    theme = bslib::bs_theme(version = 5),
    
    # Navbar
    tags$nav(
        class = "navbar navbar-light bg-light",
        
        tags$div(
            class = "container-fluid",
            
            tags$button(
                class = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle",
                type = "button",
                id = "dropdownMenuClickable",
                "data-bs-toggle" = "dropdown",
                "data-bs-auto-close" = "false",
                "Manual Close"
            ),
            
            
            tags$ul(
                class = "dropdown-menu",
                
                tags$li(
                    tags$a(
                        class = "dropdown-item",
                        "Menu Item"
                    ),
                    tags$a(
                        class = "dropdown-item",
                        "Menu Item"
                    ),
                    tags$a(
                        class = "dropdown-item",
                        "Menu Item"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: My UI structure looks like that: `ui <-fluidRow(navbarPage(tabPanel('Home',navlistPanel(tabPanel("test2,"test"),navbarMenu("info1","nav1",tabPanel("info","two"),tabPanel("nav2","three"))))`  and element which uses bootstrap is navbarMenu (with tabPanel elements). Therefore is it a way to change its behaviour directly, without  adding bootstrapPage for whole page?

Comment: You could try `shiny::tagAppendAttributes()` https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/tagappendattributes